# OpenGL: How do I access information about all the current buffers in my application?

Tags: opengl, buffer, extract

How do I access information about all the current buffers in my application? For example to know all the active VBO's being used by my application on a certain frame.

Edit 1:
Colonel Thirty Two's and Reto Koradi's answers do gave me a general idea to obtain buffer information, it seems the application did not show any buffer with (`glGetVertexAttribiv`), however I managed to list my current buffers with:

```
GLint isEnabled = GL_TRUE;
for (GLint iAttrib = 1; isEnabled; ++iAttrib) {
    isEnabled = glIsBuffer(iAttrib);
    if (isEnabled) {
        //I'm listing all buffer data in a string vector at the moment
        bufferInfoData.push_back("Buffer: " + std::to_string(iAttrib) + ">");
    }
}
```

This results in the following output from buffers 1 to 15:

```
Buffer: 1>
Buffer: 2>
Buffer: 3>
... etc etc
Buffer: 14>
Buffer: 15>
```

However i'd like to know which type and data within those buffers, also I'm not sure if counting buffers until one isn't enabled is the right way to list then all.

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GlGet

Answer (score 2):

To get all buffers that are used for a currently enabled vertex attribute, you could use code like this:

```
GLint nAttrib = 0;
glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS, &nAttrib);
for (GLint iAttrib = 0; iAttrib < nAttrib; ++iAttrib) {
    GLint isEnabled = GL_FALSE;
    glGetVertexAttribiv(iAttrib, GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_ENABLED, &isEnabled);
    if (isEnabled) {
        GLint bufferId = 0;
        glGetVertexAttribiv(iAttrib, GL_VERTEX_ATTRIB_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING, &bufferId);
    }
}
```

Note that this will give you the same buffer multiple times if it's used for multiple attributes.

Comment: Thanks, by the way you forgot the R in GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS